# Upstart unknown job error on amazon server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, upstart

I am trying to deploy my first upstart job to reload my server if it crashes but no matter what I put into the job it gives error of unknown job. Even if I have the job doing nothing only comments. 
This is the job. only few lins. I'm using emacs

```
 # comment
 description "golf"
 script
    export HOME="/root"

     exec sudo -u  
  ubuntu /usr/local/bin/node 
    /home/ubuntu/golf/node/lib/db-server1.js  2>&1
   >> /var/log/golf.log 
      end script
```

The paths are correct but I always get error unknown job Golf, even if I remove everything. Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the service name does not match what you expect. Most notably, the upper-case `G` is quite unusual. Are you certain that there's a service definition in `/etc/init.d/Golf.conf`, as opposed to `/etc/init.d/golf.conf` (note the lower-case g)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My apologies the error was unknown job golf not with a capital. One problem I had was I did not call the job golf.conf but even with this I have not got it started. I have the job in /etc/init/ but even if I put it into /etc/init.d I get the same error. No matter waht I put in the job I get the error. I tried to install upstart again, but it told me I was up todate.

Comment: I changed the code to the following, changing the names of the directories, but not matter what I try nothing works. I got forever working alright.  start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

respawn
chdir /home/ubuntu/node-monitor/run
exec /usr/local/bin/node client.js ec2=true debug=false console=true cloudwatch=true >>